# What's the current thinking on selecting model complexity in the statistical community?

Tags: model-selection, regularization

I was watching [a recent presentation by a neural networks researcher](http://sms.cam.ac.uk/media/2017973) who recommended using a model more complex than would be suggested by the data, and regularizing the life out of it. He said this yielded better results in machine learning tasks than matching the complexity to the data, as is the tradition.

I realize this is a bit hand-wavey since it comes from a high-level presentation, so does anybody have something concrete to add; relevant papers or a mathematical argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some benefit of that approach.  In the regression model world this means fitting an additive model including lots of mean effects, with each continuous variable expanded using regression splines.  Then use penalized maximum likelihood estimation (e.g., quadratic or ridge penalty).  This can result in superior prediction and lack of overfitting.

"Suggested by the data" is the only problematic piece of your question.  The data are typically not capable of making sensible suggestions about themselves especially in the large $p$ and not so large $n$ case.